# From Eclipse to PhpStorm: Cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: eclipse, phpstorm

I switched from Eclipse to PhpStorm 10. In Eclipse I can go to the class `$x = "Xclass";`  by <kbd>Ctrl + left mouse click</kbd> on `"Xclass"`.  But in PhpStrom i get the message : `Cannot find declaration to go to`.

I'm looking since more than one hour to get it to run.

The problem is that I use this kind of declaration ( `$x = "Xclass";` ) very often.

Comment: PhpStorm does not treat *random string content* as class names unfortunately. Your options: 1) install "Navigate From Literal" plugin .. and if you have a file named like that (`Xclass` in your case) it will take you there. 2) Just select the class name (double click or any other means) and use `Navigate | Class..` -- it should enter the selected text into search box by default.

Answer (score 2):

**Foo.php**

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class Foo
{
    private $bar = 'foo';

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include 'Foo.php';
use Foo\Foo;

$class = 'Foo\Foo';
$foo = new $class();
echo $foo->getBar();
```

Navigation on `$class = 'Foo\Foo';` won't work by default. You can cropy the class and use <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>  to use PhpStorm's [Classsearch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html?origin=old_help).

To be able to use <kbd>Ctrl + Left Mouse</kbd> you have to install `Navigate From Literal`.

```
File > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories > Search > Navigate From Literal
```

If you are using Proxy you have to change the settings before being able to browse the repositories.

Comment: LazyOne and Horst Jahns: Thank you for the answerts, both of them works very fine. Horst Jahns: The problem is, that this not realy works in leagacy code (one file with n classes, file- and class name is not the same ...)